# bash var substitution inside json to use in curl

Tags: bash, environment-variables, json, variable-substitution

Team,
I am unable to substitute values inside json`(myjson)` to use in curl command. any hint?

```
JENKINS_USERNAME="svc-user"
JENKINS_USER_TOKEN="xxxx"
JENKINS_INSTANCE_FQDN="sham.blsm.comp.com"
INSTANCE="test-verify"
CREDENTIAL_ID_NAME="test"
USERNAME_KEY="tests"
USER_PASSWORD_KEY="testst"
ID_DESCRIPTION="asdfasdfasdf"
```

```
myjson=\''{ 
            "credentials": {
                "scope": "GLOBAL",
                "id": "'"${CREDENTIAL_ID_NAME}"'",
                "username": "'"${USERNAME_KEY}"'", 
                "password": "'"${USER_PASSWORD_KEY}"'",
                "description": "'"${ID_DESCRIPTION}"'",
                "\$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
            }
        }'\'
curl -X POST https://${JENKINS_USERNAME}:${JENKINS_USER_TOKEN}@${JENKINS_INSTANCE_FQDN}/${JENKINS_INSTANCE}/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials \
--data-urlencode ${myjson}
```

output

```
curl -X POST https://${JENKINS_USERNAME}:${JENKINS_USER_TOKEN}@${JENKINS_INSTANCE_FQDN}/${JENKINS_INSTANCE}/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials \
--data-urlencode ${myjson}
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
{
 ^
```

below answer did not help me
[Bash variable substitution in a JSON string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312702/bash-variable-substitution-in-a-json-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes are part of the command line, not part of the value. They are removed in quote expansion before curl gets the value, so don't include them.

```bash
myjson='{ 
            "credentials": {
                "scope": "GLOBAL",
                "id": "'"${CREDENTIAL_ID_NAME}"'",
                "username": "'"${USERNAME_KEY}"'", 
                "password": "'"${USER_PASSWORD_KEY}"'",
                "description": "'"${ID_DESCRIPTION}"'",
                "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
            }
        }'
```

(Note that the dollar sign needs no escaping in single quotes.)

You need to double quote the variable if you want to prevent word splitting:

```bash
curl -X POST https://${JENKINS_USERNAME}:${JENKINS_USER_TOKEN}@${JENKINS_INSTANCE_FQDN}/${JENKINS_INSTANCE}/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials \
--data-urlencode "${myjson}"
```

Note that this only works if no variable contains a double quote. It's better to use a JSON-aware tool to handle more complex cases, I'd recommend studying [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).

Comment: thanks.. at least am not getting the curl error now with your help but somehow the server is returning 404 where as it works perfectly when I use static values. so may be `$class` is not being intercepted?

Comment: Please update the question with the JSON you expect to get.

Comment: your answer worked on jenkins server pod. so am happy thanks.

Comment: This would unfortunately fail if the password contains double quotes or other characters that need to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to create a JSON document from a set of shell variables is by using `jq`.  This ensures that each string value is encoded appropriately if needed (e.g. if the password includes double quotes or backslashes or other characters that need encoding in JSON).

```bash
payload=$(
    jq -n \
        --arg scope GLOBAL \
        --arg id "$CREDENTIAL_ID_NAME" \
        --arg username "$USERNAME_KEY" \
        --arg password "$USER_PASSWORD_KEY" \
        --arg description "$ID_DESCRIPTION" \
        --arg '$class' com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl \
        '{ credentials: $ARGS.named }'
)
```

`$ARGS.named` is a JSON object containing all the keys+values defined with `--arg` on the `jq` command line (use `--argjson` if a value is already an encoded JSON value).

Given the variables shown in the question, this would create a `payload` shell variable with the following contents (use `jq` with its `-c` option to create more compact output):

```json
{
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "test",
    "username": "tests",
    "password": "testst",
    "description": "asdfasdfasdf",
    "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
  }
}
```

For a user password that is the string `"""''\\\!!` followed by the invisible character produced by <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, the `password` key's value would automatically be encoded as the JSON string `\"\"\"''\\\\\\!!\u0007`.

You would then use that with `curl`, just remember to double quote the expansion of the variable.